# append script doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, append, appendchild

I am using this script to dynamically add scripts that loads graph in my [page](http://www.s-maof.com/shorts/shorts_table.php).
This code works fine in chrome, Safari and FF but not in IE(!!)..

```
$.post("shorts.server.php", $.param({

    S_number: stocknumber,

}), function(response) {

    script = document.createElement('script');
    //dynamic_graph.js changes it's content by the current selected stock
    script.src = 'jQuery/head/dynamic_graph.js';
    $("#graphMain" + id).append(script);

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = 'jQuery/head/dynamic_info.js';

    head.appendChild(script);
});​
```

1. you can see that I tried both techniques to append the scripts dynamically.
2. they both don't work in IE. can you suggest a better way to append the scripts?
   1 more less important but related question:

   1. what is the currect way to post a script in stackoverflow??, because sometimes it's colored and sometimes it's grayed...

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to append dynamic elements to the DOM in IE a while ago, I found that I needed to do it the other way round to get it to work. So instead of

```
$("#graphMain" + id).append(script);
```

try

```
$(script).appendTo($("#graphMain" + id));
```

Comment: hi clark, thank for the reply. I tried it and it errored me with "script.appendTo is not a function"

Comment: thanks. but that doesn't work either. I have read many posts here (like [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090198/using-appendchild-with-ie-in-javascript and [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436710/element-appendchild-chokes-in-ie) but I need to append a script to the body tag, AND I NEED TO DO IT A FEW TIME , everytime the user presses a row