# Cross browser issue with script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code that will dynamically create the script tag.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Applying</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, 
        function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
    return vars;
}
var variable1 = getUrlVars()["parameter1"];    

var myScript = document.createElement('script');

myScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
myScript.setAttribute('urlId', '420');
myScript.setAttribute('dataTitle', variable1);
myScript.setAttribute('dataemail', 'admin@domain.net');

document.body.appendChild(myScript);                              
</script>

<input name="Apply" type="button" id="Apply" value="Apply" ONCLICK="window.location.href='https://www.google.com?'">

</body>
</html>
```

But somehow the above code doesn't work in IE but it works fine in Chrome. I am not sure what is the reason? Can anybody help me with that?

This whole things doesn't work in IE.

```
var myScript = document.createElement('script');

myScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
myScript.setAttribute('urlId', '420');
myScript.setAttribute('dataTitle', variable1);
myScript.setAttribute('dataemail', 'admin@domain.net');

document.body.appendChild(myScript);
```

Comment: I don’t see you adding any actual JS code to that script element – so what exactly do you want it to do when it “works” …?

Comment: Your generated `<script>` doesn't seem to have a _src_ or any contents.

Comment: Also, how doesn't it work? Do you get an error?

Comment: What does it do in Chrome?

Comment: @mplungjan Why is that? They append it to the body

Comment: By the way, add a doctype to your page

Comment: `document.body.appendChild` works in IE? I believe it's a known issue?

Comment: @CBroe, There should be some other way around for this. As `document.body.appendChild` doesn't works properly in IE for me. I am using IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically add a script element using the following function.

```
   var create_script = function(data) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.text = data;

        //if you have to debug dynamically loaded script in chrome use the following - sourceURL has changed in the recent versions of chrome devetools.
        //script.text = data + "\n\n //@ sourceURL=" + ns + ".js\n";

        //append the script element to body or head or where it seems fit.
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
```

the "data" parameter is the actual javascript code/URL that will form the part of the script tag. You are missing this in your code.

EDIT:
for non-standard attributes you might want to change the doctype according to http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/dtd_attributes.asp

Comment: But I have other properties as well to add it. And also document.body.appendChild works in IE? I believe it's a known issue?

Comment: This could be browser dependent - but the script tag should support attributed mentioned here - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp and also the global attributes mentioned in here - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

Comment: Yes it is not working in IE and I need to make sure it should also work in IE as well.

Comment: have you tried modifying the doctype to the following   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[
  <!ATTLIST tag myAttri CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>

Comment: @TechGeeky no such known issue with IE, but yes IE is slow and it's behaviour with element and all it's parent having being parsed is a little different from other browsers. Can you try to run the script on the onload event. I am quite hopeful that it might work then.

Comment: The script type hasn't been needed in browsers for many years.

Comment: @Rob Yes, and I assume that it is because the default type is text/javascript. For any other types it is required, so i put it in there for completeness.

Comment: I have tried that as well and still it doesn't worked for me. I have seen various other stackoverflow post in which users have complained about `document.body.appendChild ` doesn't work in IE.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090198/using-appendchild-with-ie-in-javascript)

Comment: @TechGeeky It seems to work for me. But I am using the IE7/IE8/IE9 user-agent in safari.

Comment: @TechGeeky fired up the win 7 VM and tested the same on native IE this time.. same result.. works for me.

Comment: Can you provide me an example basis on onLoad event that you suggested me initially basis on my example above.?