# appendChild not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to pass in either a tag or id to append the content and js files.  As usual this works in every browser except ie, ie only works with document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild.  Is there a fix for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/qg5zexmh/

```
// Append js and html.
function _append(selector, arr) {
    var content = arr;
    for(var i = 0; i< content.length; i++) {
        var _content = content[i];
        var js = _content.indexOf('script');
        if(js > -1) {
            // Script tag.
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            var regex = /<script.*?src="(.*?)"/gmi;
            var url = regex.exec(_content);
            var inline = '';
            if(url) {
              script.src = url[1];
            } else {
              _content.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(){
                inline += arguments[1] + '\n';
              });
              script.text = inline;
            }
            //document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
            selector.appendChild(script);
        } else {
            // html content.
            selector.innerHTML += _content;
        }
    }
}
// Selector - div or tag.
var selector = document.getElementById('content');
```

Comment: Check this may help you [append child with ie][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090198/using-appendchild-with-ie-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appendChild works with created elements or DOMparser (although DOMparser doesn't natively work with safari/webkit), also appending a script to a selector isn't cross browser friendly, it needs to be appended to the head or body tag directly.

When using appendChild with html the simplest way would be

```
var str = '<h1>string of html</h1>';
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = str;
selector.appendChild(d);
```

Answer (score -1):

appendChild works with inline javascript but you must use document.write('</script>'); for external scripts to get it to work in ie.  Works back to ie8.